# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status') in axios

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, rapidapi

This is the code from the freecodecamp tutorial (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-react-based-code-editor/), the code is meant for react but my project is for next js and when I run it in the react project I don't get this error but when I run it in the next js project I get the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
```

The code where the error is occurring according to the error message.

```
axios
        .request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("res.data", response.data);
            const token = response.data.token;
            checkStatus(token);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            let error = err.response ? err.response.data : err;
            // get error status
            let status = err.response.status;
            console.log("status", status);
            if (status === 429) {
                console.log("too many requests", status);

                showErrorToast(
                    `Quota of 100 requests exceeded for the Day! Please read the blog on freeCodeCamp to learn how to setup your own RAPID API Judge0!`,
                    10000
                );
            }
            setProcessing(false);
            console.log("catch block...", error);
        });
};
```

Comment: Is it the typo, you have `let error...` then `err.response.status`. Should it be `error.response.status`?

Comment: Just in general though, it is saying it cannot read `status` of an undefined variable. That means in your code, `err.response` is undefined. Try console logging `err` right at the top of the `catch((err)) => { console.log(err)` and see if you can find a `status` property

Comment: if you remove everything in that catch block except `console.log(err)` you get undefined? I don't think you do, otherwise I'm pretty sure the error would say `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')`

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, I think that the problem is that before this code I tried to pull some api keys from .env file which aren't getting pulled from there. However I am not sure about how to get a variable from the .env file.

Comment: Thats good, maybe best to start a new question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Axious [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors). Looks like you are not even receiving a response, meaning `error.response` is left undefined. Maybe something wrong with the request options?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, I think that the problem is that before this code I tried to pull some api keys from .env file which aren't getting pulled from there. However I am not sure about how to get a variable from the .env file.